# Lines either side of date header

Tags: css

Im using the following CSS to create two lines either side of my date header

```
.date-header span {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;  
}
.date-header span:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
border-bottom: 1px solid #caa69a;
top: 6px;
width: 160%;
left: 110%;
}
.date-header span::before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #caa69a;
width: 160%;
right: 110%;
}
```

However the lines change size according to the length of the date. I'd like the lines to stay a fixed a length. I'm not sure what to edit or to add?

Comment: If you want a fixed width for the lines...change the `width` property?

Comment: You should probably not use a percentage as the width unit.  Try using `px` instead?

Comment: I've tried using px instead but it still changes according to the length of the date.